# Include tabbedpage in a Xamarin forms popup

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup, tabbedpage

I have a popup on click of a list view.
Is it possible to include Tabbed page in the popup with two tabs?

Comment: Hi @Sai Sunkari,  did you get, I am struck with the same issue

Comment: @sahithi no. I made an alternative like put 2 buttons(like tab headers) and populate the view/page based on the button click.

Comment: Oh okay @Sai Sunkari, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what effect is your want.Follow is one way :

```
async void OnAlertYesNoClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool answer = await DisplayAlert ("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
  Debug.WriteLine ("Answer: " + answer);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @SaiSunkari Hi. Sorry for not tabs.It needs custom renderer in native platform.If have solution will share here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want tabs without having a `TabbedPage` in Xamarin.Forms, you can use those custom tabs:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms#pure-xamarinforms-tabs-no-renderers

These are simple xamarin forms views, you can put them everywhere you like.